# Preparing data for Keras custom training loop with image and meta input and number of samples seen

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I've been following [this tutorial](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/) on building a custom training loop with keras from scratch and trying to apply it to my problem.

I have a set of (71x71x3) shaped images with an additional meta for each image that is a float number.

To apply this to the tutorial I used the following code for data preparation:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 64

# Prepare the training dataset.
t1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_train, meta_train))
t2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(label_train)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((t1,t2))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)

# Prepare the validation dataset.
v1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_test, meta_test))
v2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(label_test)


val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((v1,v2))
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

However, when I start training with the exact code provided in the tutorial:

```py
epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
        # Open a GradientTape to record the operations run
        # during the forward pass, which enables auto-differentiation.
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Run the forward pass of the layer.
            # The operations that the layer applies
            # to its inputs are going to be recorded
            # on the GradientTape.
            logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch

            # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

        # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
        # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

        # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
        # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

        # Log every 200 batches.
        if step % 200 == 0:
            print(
                "Training loss (for one batch) at step %d: %.4f"
                % (step, float(loss_value))
            )
            print("Seen so far: %s samples" % ((step + 1) * batch_size))
```

the samples "seen so far" do not increase opposed to the tutorial:

### My training output:

```
Start of epoch 0
Training loss (for one batch) at step 0: 201.9029
Seen so far: 64 samples

Start of epoch 1
Training loss (for one batch) at step 0: 0.1668
Seen so far: 64 samples

Start of epoch 2
Training loss (for one batch) at step 0: 0.1449
Seen so far: 64 samples

Start of epoch 3
Training loss (for one batch) at step 0: 0.2491
Seen so far: 64 samples
```

### Keras tutorial:

```
Start of epoch 0
Training loss (for one batch) at step 0: 155.5935
Seen so far: 64 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 200: 1.3908
Seen so far: 12864 samples
Training loss (for one batch) at step 400: 1.1934
Seen so far: 25664 samples
```

The rest of the training seems fine and the model seems to work. But I'm not sure whether it is doing what it's supposed to do.

I've changed the `batch_size` but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the same dataset? As I see it, there is no problem: your dataset just seems smaller (or using larger batch_size).

What happens is that the counter of seen examples so far is for each epoch: it restarts on each epoch, so, as can see in your output, each "block" of output is for a different epoch, and hence, the counter restarted. However, in the keras example the counter is increased on each because all are under the same epoch.